Is there a way to create 2 downstream flux from 1 upstream flux without calling collectList()
I have an upstream flux given Flux<Item> and I would like to create 2 independent downstream flux where filter/filterWhen on Flux 1 would not affect Flux 2. The downstream flux would look like the following

Flux 1


For each item, there would be filter and filterWhen to apply to each item to filter it out from the Flux stream and this should not affect Flux 2


Flux 2


The final output of this would be equivalent to Flux<Item>.collectList()

So ideally it would look something like this. Take note that I’m just trying to lay out the idea that I want to execute so the code will not be entirely accurate
 Flux<item> itemFlux = Flux.fromIterable(someItemList)
        .transform(upstreamFlux ->
          Tuples.of(
              // create Flux 1
              Flux.from(upstreamFlux)
                  .filter(someFilter...)
                  .filterWhen(anotherFilter...)
              // create Flux 2
              Flux.from(upstreamFlux),
          )

        )

It’s currently possible to get my results but I would have to call collectList() and make Flux 1 wait until all Items from upstream are collected.
Flux<item> itemFlux = Flux.fromIterable(someItemList)         
            .collectList()              
                .flatMap(collectedItemList ->                       
                    Tuples.of(                              
                        Flux.from(collectedItemList )                                       
                            .filter(someFilter...)                                      
                            .filterWhen(anotherFilter...)                                       
                            .collectList()                              
                        Flux.from(collectedItemList).collectList()                      
                    )               
            )

To provide further context, the upstream flux has already gone through heavy computation and send a lot of HTTP requests so ideally I don't want to recreate the upstream flux. I have looked into Flux.publish() and Flux.cache() but I don't exactly see how I can make use of them for this particular scenario.
